# RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to get to grips with Pytorch and I wanted to try to reproduce this code:

https://github.com/andy-psai/MountainCar_ActorCritic/blob/master/RL%20Blog%20FINAL%20MEDIUM%20code%2002_12_19.ipynb

in Pytorch.

I am having a problem in that this error is being returned:

RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

A similar question said to use zero_grad() again after the optimizer step, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

I've included the entire code below so hopefully it should be reproduceable.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import gym
import os
import os.path as osp
import time
import math
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.distributions import Normal

env = gym.envs.make("MountainCarContinuous-v0")

# Value function

class Value(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim_states):
        super(Value, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(dim_states, 400),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(400,400),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(400, 1)
    )
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr = 1e-3)
        self.criterion = nn.MSELoss()

    def forward(self, state):
        return self.net(torch.from_numpy(state).float())

    def compute_return(self, output, target):
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = self.criterion(output, target)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()

# Policy network

class Policy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim_states, env):
        super(Policy, self).__init__()

        self.hidden1 = nn.Linear(dim_states, 40)
        self.hidden2 = nn.Linear(40, 40)
        self.mu = nn.Linear(40, 1)
        self.sigma = nn.Linear(40,1)
        self.env = env

        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr = 2e-5)

    def forward(self, state):
        state = torch.from_numpy(state).float()
        x = F.relu(self.hidden1(state))
        x = F.relu(self.hidden2(x))
        mu = self.mu(x)
        sigma = F.softmax(self.sigma(x), dim=-1)
        action_dist = Normal(mu, sigma)
        action_var = action_dist.rsample()
        action_var = torch.clip(action_var,
                        self.env.action_space.low[0],
                        self.env.action_space.high[0])

        return action_var, action_dist

    def compute_return(self, action, dist, td_error):
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_actor = -dist.log_prob(action)*td_error
        loss_actor.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()

# Normalise the state space
import sklearn
import sklearn.preprocessing

state_space_samples = np.array(
    [env.observation_space.sample() for x in range(10000)])
scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(state_space_samples)

# Normaliser
def scale_state(state):
    scaled = scaler.transform([state])
    return scaled
##################################

# Parameters

lr_actor = 0.00002
lr_critic = 0.001

actor = Policy(2, env)
critic = Value(2)

# Training loop params
gamma = 0.99
num_episodes = 300

episode_history = []

for episode in range(num_episodes):

    # Receive initial state from E

    state = env.reset()
    reward_total = 0
    steps = 0
    done = False

    while not done:

        action, dist = actor(state)

        # print(np.squeeze(action))
        next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(
                                        np.array([action.item()]))

        if episode % 50 == 0:
            env.render()

        steps += 1
        reward_total += reward

        # TD Target
        target = reward + gamma * np.squeeze(critic(next_state), axis=0)

        td_error = target - np.squeeze(critic(state), axis=0)

        # Update actor
        actor.compute_return(action, dist, td_error)

        # Update critic
        critic.compute_return(np.squeeze(critic(state), axis=0), target)


    episode_history.append(reward_total)

    print(f"Episode: {episode}, N Steps: {steps}, Cumulative reward {reward_total}")

    if np.mean(episode_history[-100:]) > 90 and len(episode_history) > 101:
        print("Solved")
        print(f"Mean cumulative reward over 100 episodes {np.mean(episode_history[-100:])}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies in this snippet. When you create `target` variable, there is a forward pass through `critic` which generates a computation graph and `critic(next_state)` is the leaf node of that graph making `target` a part of the graph (you can check this by printing `target` which will show you `grad_fn=<AddBackward0>`). Finally, when you call `critic.compute_return(critic_out, target)`, a new computation graph is generated and passing `target`(which is a part of the previous computation graph) causes a Runtime error.

Solution is to call `detach()` on `critic(next_state)`, this will free `target` variable and it will no longer be a part of the computation graph(again check by printing `target`).

```
target = reward + gamma * np.squeeze(critic(next_state).detach(), axis=0)
td_error = target - np.squeeze(critic(state), axis=0)

# Update actor
actor.compute_return(action, dist, td_error)

# Update critic
critic_out = np.squeeze(critic(state), axis=0)
print(critic_out)
critic.compute_return(critic_out, target)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I needed!